# OpenGL Simple Frag and Vertex Shader

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am trying to make a sphere, shaded a color, except for a circle centered on the yz origin, which I want to dilate and constrict (already have a time variable based on the runtime repeating at 5s, thinking I'll just use that and a sin function.)  However I don't know how to implement the control to change color within the circle on the sphere.

Here's my main function within my frag shader:

```glsl
vec3 myColor = vec3( 0, 1., 0. );

float uSize = 0.2;

if( vST.t > .4 && vST.t < .6 && vST.s > .4 && vST.s < .6)
{
    myColor = vec3( 1., 0., 0. );
}

gl_FragColor = vec4( myColor,  1. );
```

Right now its just a green sphere, except a box between s / t 0.4 -> 0.6 which is red. vST is the vertex s/t coords.

Comment: It's a box because you're checking the bounds of a box that's 0.2 x 0.2. You should check the distance between `vST` and the point `0.5, 0.5`. Also, `vST` is not the vertex s/t coords. It's the fragment's coordinates.

Comment: Whoops st coordinates from the vertex shader is what I should've said. Thank you for the direction

Comment: Note that the st coordinates from the vertex shader are interpolated before being passed to the fragment shader. Those are still fragment-dependent values, not vertex-dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `if( ... )` with `if(distance(vST, center)<radius)`.

Better yet, make it antialiased and replace the `if` with `mix`.  Like so:

```c
float dist = distance(uv, center);
float aa = fwidth(dist);
float inside = smoothstep(radius - aa, radius + aa, dist);
myColor = mix(color0, color1, inside);
```

Demo at https://www.shadertoy.com/view/tsGXWh